# I'd like to open the app settings page from a Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin

I need to open the app settings page for my Xamarin Android app.

Using Java, it seems that the correct way to do it is:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
              Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)));
```

So, using C#, I tried:

```
StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings,
              Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + BuildConfig.ApplicationId)));
```

This does nothing...
I tried without the Uri parameter, and in that case I get an exception:

```
Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS }
```

I also tried

```
StartActivityForResult(
    new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings), 0);
```

Same exception...

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found the issue!

In

```
StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings,
          Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + BuildConfig.ApplicationId)));
```

It's the

```
BuildConfig.ApplicationId
```

that doesn't work...

The correct call (or at least the one that worked for me) using Xamarin is then

```
StartActivity(new Intent(
    Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings,
    Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:"+ Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName)));
```

Comment: good info.  Only is anyone aware how to further dig down into this "App info" menu?
Id like to get into the "Permissions" menu, and if at all possible. Further select items in its listing

Comment: @axa - not possible

Answer (score 11):

```
Xamarin.Essentials.AppInfo.ShowSettingsUI();
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Using Xamarin through Visual Studio and C#, I switched to `Application.Context.PackageName` too.

I kept finding Java examples using `BuildConfig.ApplicationId`, but in C#, that caused me to run into your same problems. Our goals are different, but I wanted to affirm that your syntax got me one step further towards mine.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Net;
...
StartActivity(new Intent(
    Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings, 
    Uri.Parse("package:" + Application.Context.PackageName)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @Sylvain and @Mikish answer,

I got an **Exception:**

> `Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: 'Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.`

Hence slightly modifying the answer:

```cs
public void OpenSettings()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings,
                    Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + Application.Context.PackageName));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```